# Center Editext in a Linear Layout - Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'm trying to center the editText which you can see in this screen (the one on the black buttons):
[image]

This is my code. I set the **android:gravity="center_horizontal"** tag, but as you can see it doesn't works. I do not understand if I need to set it at the center of its linear layout or if I need to pay attention to the external linear layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FCFCFC"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    tools:context=".PaintingActivity" >

    <!-- Top Buttons -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/draw_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/brush"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/brush" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/erase_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/erase"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/eraser" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/undo_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:contentDescription="Undo"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/undo" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/colorPicker"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"
            android:contentDescription="colorPicker"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/palette" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Custom View -->

    <com.example.williamstest.DrawingView
        android:id="@+id/drawing"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FFFFFFFF" />

    <!-- Menu in basso -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <!-- Top Row -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/toprow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_70sdp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edittitle"
                android:layout_width="400dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
                android:layout_marginBottom="25dip"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Inserisci qui il titolo"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
                android:singleLine="true"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- Bottom Row -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottomrow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="120dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bb_3"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
                android:text="Indietro"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bb_2"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
                android:text="Avanti"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you don't need that LinearLayout which encloses the EditText. Remove it, and it will work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use `layout_marginLeft` to align it `center_horizontal`, remove it. Just add `android:gravity` to `center_horizontal` in your `LinearLayout` enclosing `EditText`.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/toprow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittitle"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dip"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Inserisci qui il titolo"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
        android:singleLine="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @babbara, Check the solution

Answer (score 1):

You have a redundant left margin
Remove          `android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_70sdp"`from the`toprow`layout
or add an equal right margin

Comment: By the way there's no point keeping that LinearLayout, it can be removed.